# Book recommendation for real numbers construction and set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Here, particularly I'm looking for a book which starts with set theory and constructs real numbers on that basis (it should include Dedekind cut). Other than Landau's book.

Edit: Thank you all in comments for your suggestions. I found this book 'From natural numbers to quaternions' by Kramer and Pippich (thought bit advanced atleast for me but very readable), Elementary Set theory by Enderton (Thanks to Asaf Karagila), Goldrei's book is also really good (Thanks to palmpo). Last two books I mentioned do both jobs of constructing numbers and introducing set theory really well.

Comment: Bourbaki, if you have enough patience.

Comment: @CaveJohnson What's the title of that book? I've almost completed naive set theory, it doesn't explain construction of real numbers. Any recommendation combining both of these aspects (set theory, number construction).

Comment: One book that gets to Dedekind's construction of the real numbers early on is Dasgupta's *Set Theory*, Springer, 2014.  Moschovachis's *Notes on Set Theory* has an appendix on the real numbers.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi yeah that helps. Thanks

Comment: Maybe John Stillwell's *The Real Numbers: An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis*?

Comment: @HansLundmark Stillwell's this book looks more focused towards set theory  rather than construction of numbers via set theory. But I found this book 'From Natural numbers to quaternions by Kramer and Pippich. Thanks for suggestion though!

Comment: Try Goldrei's _Classic Set Theory_, it constructs real numbers from rationals, rationals from integers, etc. until they have to construct sets from set theory.